# how to declare use bind to call a separate function as even handler in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-pagescroller

I have a this block of code which will work fine:

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now I want to manipulate the code a bit: creating a pageScroll function, and let it be the event handler inside bind():

```
//page scroll function 
$.fn.pageScroll = function(){

    ////Create a new jQuery.Event object without the "new" operator.
    var event = $.Event( "click" );
    // prevent browser to operate as default on the event
    event.preventDefault();

    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
};
// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
// call pageScroll() function for click event on page-scroll class of <a> tag

$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', $().pageScroll(event));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you execute the 'pageScroll' function.
By that you send to the bind function the response of the 'pageScroll' function rather then the pointer to the function.

So basically all you need to do is replace this:

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', $().pageScroll(event));
```

with this

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', $().pageScroll);
```

Comment: Your answer is CORRECT ! THANK YOU !!!

My concept of JQuery is not solid. I still don't understand how changing from pageScroll(event) to only pageScroll makes the whole thing work. 

I thought that I have to put a "callback function" into bind(). 

Bind('click', $().pageScroll()  doesn't quite use a callback, but still use a function to executed; the result of the execution is being used as a parameter for bind(). The parameter is a event handler 

Now my question is: is that how we should call another function within another function in Javascript/Jquery? Is it just a syntax rule?

Comment: by putting ' $().pageScroll()' (Notice the () at the end) you execute the 'pateScroll' function and send to 'bind' function the value returned from that execution, and without '()' at the end, you send the function iteslf.